# How to remove blur effect on Swiper js slider in the IOS devices

Tags: jquery, css, ios, slider, swiper.js

I have created a slider using Swiper js (https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api). Everything looks great except the slider image in the IOS devices. The image looks blurry on the IOS devices. I have checked on the android devices but there is no blur effect.

Here is my configuration of Swiper JS:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                observer: true,
                observeParents: true,
                roundLengths: true,
                slidesPerView: 2,
                speed: 1000,
                spaceBetween: 50,
                centeredSlides: true,
                grabCursor: false,
                loop: true,
                pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                    clickable: true,
                },
                autoplay: {
                    delay: 2000,
                },
                navigation: {nextEl: '.swiper-button-next', prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'},
                allowTouchMove: true,
                cssMode: false,
                breakpoints: {
                    600 : {
                        slidesPerView: 2,
                    },

                    1024: {
                        slidesPerView: 3,
                    }
                },

            });
```

Here is the link to the site: https://tokona.nishalgurung.name.np

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It might just be that iOS devices typically have a higher screen DPI - have you tried using higher resolution images and seeing if that makes a difference?

Comment: Just tried with a higher resolution but still looks blur.